# 日本語に違和感: 「クローズ」する時のダイアログ内の文言

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

#### 右上の x ボタン

> このポップアップを閉じてください (または Esc キーを押してください)

#### 最初の画面のタイトル

> この質問をクローズべき理由は何ですか?

「すべき」

#### 最初の画面の理由の 1 つ

> 次の理由でトピックから外れている...

「トピックから外れている」が伝わりにくいように思います。それとも一般的な言い方でしょうか

#### 最初の画面の理由の 1 つ

> 質問の意味が不明

もう少しやわらかい言い方がいいように思います

#### 最初の画面の理由の 1 つ

> 範囲が広すぎる
>   考えられる回答が多すぎるか、または良質な回答をしようとすると長くなりすぎてこの形式に収まらないと思われます。   回答を絞り込めるように詳細を追加するか、数パラグラフ内に回答が収まるように問題点を分けてください。

「良質」「この形式」「パラグラフ」に違和感

#### 最初の画面の理由の 1 つ

> 主に意見を述べている
>   良質な質問であっても、それに対する回答に深い経験に基づく意見が含まれることはありますが、この質問に対しては、  事実、参考情報、特定の専門知識ではなく、ほぼ意見に基づく回答ばかりが集まりそうです。

「主に意見を述べている」「良質」に違和感。また、文が長くてわかりにくい

#### 「次の理由でトピックから外れている...」を選択した時のパンくずリスト

> トピックから外れている

上の「次の理由でトピックから外れている...」と同じ

#### トピックから外れている > Other を選択した時のテキストエリアの内容

> この質問は次の内容なので、トピックから外れているようです:

「次の内容なので」に違和感

#### 「移行」先のアイコンの alt 属性

> 次のアイコン: meta.ja.stackoverflow.com

「次のアイコン」に違和感

Comment: コメントされた回答意外適用済です。

Answer (score 1):

#### 最初の画面のタイトル

> この質問をクローズべき理由は何ですか?

この質問をクローズすべき理由は何ですか？

Answer (score 1):

#### 最初の画面の理由の 1 つ

> 主に意見を述べている
>   良質な質問であっても、それに対する回答に深い経験に基づく意見が含まれることはありますが、この質問に対しては、  事実、参考情報、特定の専門知識ではなく、ほぼ意見に基づく回答ばかりが集まりそうです。

主観的な答えしか集まらない

どんなに模範的な、百科事典レベルの答えでも、経験に基づく主観性はある程度入るものです。しかしこの質問の場合、どんな答えも個人的な意見や感想になると思われます。確かな情報ソースや専門知識と経験、事実に基づいた回答ができるような質問にしてください。

原文:

Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0):

#### 右上の x ボタン

> このポップアップを閉じてください (または Esc キーを押してください)

閉じる（Esc キーでも閉じられます）

Answer (score 0):

オフトピック関係

#### 最初の画面の理由の 1 つ

> 次の理由でトピックから外れている...

オフトピックである（サイトの趣旨から外れている）...

#### 「次の理由でトピックから外れている...」を選択した時のパンくずリスト

> トピックから外れている

オフトピック

#### トピックから外れている > Other を選択した時のテキストエリアの内容

> この質問は次の内容なので、トピックから外れているようです:

サイトの趣旨から外れた質問内容です。具体的には、

Comment: 「次の理由でトピックから外れている...」と言う文書は3つあります：（１）「次の理由でトピックから外れている...」（２）「次の理由でトピックから外れている...(すでに移行されている)」（３）「次の理由でトピックから外れている...(古すぎて移行できない)」entoさんの提案でダブル括弧になりますが、大丈夫ですかね？

Answer (score 0):

#### 最初の画面の理由の 1 つ

> 質問の意味が不明

質問内容がはっきりしない

Answer (score 0):

#### 最初の画面の理由の 1 つ

> 範囲が広すぎる
>   考えられる回答が多すぎるか、または良質な回答をしようとすると長くなりすぎてこの形式に収まらないと思われます。   回答を絞り込めるように詳細を追加するか、数パラグラフ内に回答が収まるように問題点を分けてください。

質問の範囲が広すぎる

現在の質問内容では考えられる回答が多すぎる、またはまじめに答えようとするとページ内に収まりきらない長さになってしまいます。質問を編集して具体的にすることで、答えを絞り込めるようにしてください。また、焦点を絞って長くなりすぎない回答が書けるようにしてください。

Answer (score 0):

#### 「移行」先のアイコンの alt 属性

> 次のアイコン: meta.ja.stackoverflow.com

meta.ja.stackoverflow.com のアイコン