# クローズ理由: "主観性が高い" を改善したい

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

今現在、クローズ理由の一つに「主観性が高い」というものがありますが、
これは「主観性が高い **質問しか集まらない**」のように、質問に対しての説明になってしまっていて、クローズ理由を選ぶ際には不適当な説明な気がします。

**現状の表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

翻訳の経緯は分かりませんが、過去には「[主観的な回答しか集まらない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/201)」などになっていたので、こちらの方が分かりやすいのかなと思います。
(もしくは別案として「単なる意見を求めている」など)

Comment: 「主観性が高い 質問しか集まらない」というのはどこからの引用でしょうか？

Comment: 該当部分は何処かからの引用ではなく、あくまで「本来意味するところはこうだろう」というつもりで書きました。原文が単に "Opinion-based" だから翻訳もそれにつられたのだと思いますが。

Comment: それでは質問ではなく回答ではないでしょうか。

Comment: ごめんなさい「主観性が高い回答しか集まりそうにない」という質問のクローズ理由を一言にすると「主観性が高い」になるのではないかと思ってしまっておりました。更に良い文章に改善できれば嬉しいです＼(^o^)／

Answer (score 1):

タイトルにするような短い文言であることと、他の記載内容との整合性を考えると、変えるのも難しいかもしれません。
下記「主観的な質問は避けてください。」に示された例をなるべく包括的に表して、タイトルに出来るような短い文言は何か？と言うことになります。

根拠となっているだろう記述は以下のヘルプでしょう。

[どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

> ...次のような主観的な質問は避けてください。
>
> - どの回答も同様に有効:「好きな ______ は何ですか?」
> - 質問と一緒に回答も提示され、さらに他の回答を期待している:「私は ______ に ______ を使用しています。皆さんは何を使用しますか?」
> - 解決すべき実際の問題がない:「他の人が私と同じように感じるか興味があります。」
> - 自由形式の仮定的な質問をしている:「もし ______ が起きたらどうしますか?」
> - 質問を装った暴言: 「______ は最悪ですよね?」
>
> 一部の主観的な質問は許されますが、「主観的」とは「何でもあり」という意味ではありません。すべての主観的な質問は建設的であることが期待されます。

StackOverflow英語版だと「subjective questions」でGoogle翻訳だと「主観的な質問」ですね。

Opinion-basedの方はこちらのヘルプですね。今は「主に意見を述べている」になっています。Google翻訳だと「意見ベース」と直訳です。

[質問が [クローズ済み] または [改善待ち] とは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

> - 主に意見を述べている - 多様な意見に注目するディスカッションは素晴らしいですが、ここでの形式には合いません。

Comment: ヘルプセンターの翻訳も様々であることを教えてくださってありがとうございます！subjective questionsやopinion-basedをどこまで意訳して良いのか、そしてワードを統一してゆくのか、再度コミュニティで考えることができればと思います。

Answer (score 1):

現在の翻訳を「**主観的な回答しか集まらない**」に変更する方が良い、と思われる方はこちらの投稿にプラス投票をお願いいたします。

---

該当するストリングはこちらです。-> https://ja.traducir.win/strings/12625
セットで表示されるストリングはこちらです。-> https://ja.traducir.win/strings/5199

> 主観性が高い
>
> どんなに模範的な、百科事典レベルの答えでも、経験に基づく主観性はある程度入るものです。しかしこの質問の場合、どんな答えも個人的な意見や感想になると思われます。確かな情報ソースや専門知識と経験、事実に基づいた回答ができるような質問にしてください。

翻訳は、これまでスタック・オーバーフロー内で使用されたワードを使うようにしていますが、"Opinion-based"で検索をかけると次のような翻訳が上がってきます。

1. 現在のところ、こちらの「**主観性が高い**」という翻訳が表示されています。
2. 「**主に意見を**」という翻訳は、過去に「違和感がある」という[お声](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/201/14055)をいただいていたようでした。
3. 「ここには向かないタイプの質問もあります。**主観性の高い**質問や、 **掲示板の「お題」** のような質問は避けてください。」という翻訳も存在します。
4. 現在の翻訳を「**主観的な回答しか集まらない**」に変更することもできると思います。

[image: 1-4]