# "新しい質問ページ" が導入されました！

Tags: 討議

ついにやってきました！スタック・オーバーフローにおいても "新しい質問ページ" が導入されました！

[image]

> **TL; DR;**
>
> 新しい質問ページは、質問者がサイトをナビゲートしやすく、迅速に質問を改善できるようガイドすることを目的としています。質問ウィザードとこれまでの質問ページの組み合わせが新しい質問ページとなります。
>
> [ブログでのイニシアチブの詳細はこちら。 (英文)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/)

開発チーム、そして翻訳を担当してくれたスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版の[@モデレーションチーム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)と[@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki)に感謝しましょう。

この質問への回答欄にご意見をお寄せいただければ幸いです！=）

Comment: Related bug? https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3275/19110

Answer (score 5):

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

コメント欄では長くなりそうなので、別回答として改善案を投稿します。

---

> コミュニティは、特定のコーディングやアルゴリズム、言語の問題をサポートするため存在します。

**改善案:**
当サイトでは、コーディングやアルゴリズムなど、主にプログラミングに関する問題のサポートを目標としています。

> 意見に基づく質問は避けて下さい。

英語での "opinion-based question" は[クローズ理由](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3248/14055)としても出てきますが、日本語に訳すのであれば
「意見を述べただけ、または意見を求めるだけの質問は避けてください」辺りが伝えたい内容なのかなと思います。

**改善案:**
なるべく客観的に答えられる質問にしてください。

Comment: 「議論を目的とした投稿」だと意味が広すぎるかもな、と思いました。たとえばベストプラクティスを知りたい、みたいな質問も議論ではありそうです。かといってどう書けば良いのだろう……。「感想を聞くだけの質問は避けてください。」「特に裏打ちの無い意見を述べるだけの質問は避けてください。」「なるべく客観的に答えられる質問にしてください。」あたりでしょうか（意訳しすぎかもです）。

Comment: 「意見を求めたり感想を聞くだけの質問は避けてください。」は、いかがでしょうか？(cubickさんとnekketsuuuさんの改善案をあわせたバージョンです。）

Comment: 「意見」という言葉が曖昧だと思っています。「どんなアルゴリズムで解決するのが良いかご意見お聞かせください」というのも「意見」ですよね。英語の opinion のニュアンスが僕が完璧には理解できていないのだと思うのですが、日本語の「意見」とは少し差があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 元々の案には「非建設的な主観的質問は避けてください。」も含まれていたのですが、意訳しすぎかと迷った結果、現在表示されているもので発進したのでありました。

Comment: Avoid asking opinion-based questions.の和訳は「〜を避けてください」ではなく「〜にしてください」の形にした「なるべく客観的に答えられる質問にしてください。」の方が伝わりやすいのではないかと思えてきましたが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: Traducir から string が消えた件のチャットログです: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53763445#53763445

Comment: Traducirからstringが削除されましたので、開発者の[g3rv4](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/24611/g3rv4)さんに直接依頼いたしました。早ければ1-2日で変更される予定です。

Answer (score 4):

とても良い改善だと思います！

[image]

> コミュニティは、特定のコーディングやアルゴリズム、言語の問題をサポートするため存在します。
>
> 意見に基づく質問は避けて下さい。

この部分、分かるような分からないような書き方がしてあるので、何が言いたいのかをはっきりさせたいです。

おそらく 1 文目はぼんやりとした問題ではなく具体的な問題を書いて欲しいという話で、2 文目は opinion-based question が訳されたものだと思います。「コミュニティ」という言葉も日本語だとすんなりとは理解できなさそうです。また、1 文目と 2 文目で言いたいことが一緒なのかいまいち分からないのですが、ここはどういう繋がりなのでしょうか。

上手く一読で分かる書き方に変えられたらなと思います。

→ https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3277/19110 こちらの回答に話題が移りました。