# 「URLの後にテキストとダブルスペースを追加するリンク」のヒントがおかしい

Tags: バグ, markdown

リンクの書き方には三種類ありますが、質問投稿ページの「URLの後にテキストとダブルスペースを追加して、リンクにalt属性を追加」の例が本来の表示と異なっています。

現状では、 Google Chrome においてリンクの例が以下のように表示されています。ここでの問題は、三番目のリンクの**テキストがはみ出して**おり、リンクの例のはずが**リンクそのものになってしまっている**ことです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

英語版では以下の画像のようになっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]