# Markdownヘルプに書かれたハイパーリンクの記述例が正常に表示されていない

Tags: バグ, 調査中, デザイン

### 不具合事象

Markdownの記述方法を示すために、質問フォームの上部には簡易的なヘルプが書かれています。その中にハイパーリンクのMarkdownにおける記述方法が、ソースコードとともに紹介されている箇所があります。しかし、その部分が正常に表示されていないようです。

以下の画像は問題の表示を撮影したスクリーンショットです。記述例のうち一番下の例が、ハイパーリンクのソースコードではなく、表示の崩れたリンクになっていることが確認できます。

[当該文字列は ja.traducir.win 上に存在する](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/12475)ようですが、この文字列だけを見る限りでは、表示を崩すような問題があるようには見えませんでした。

[image: 不具合が生じている質問ページのスクリーンショット。記述例のうち一番下の例が、期待されるようなソースコード形式ではなく、表示の崩れたリンク形式になっていることが確認できる。]

### 再現環境

- OS：Windows 10 64-bit
- ブラウザ：Opera One(バージョン: 104.0.4944.36)

Comment: ロシア語版やスペイン語版では問題ないので、日本語版固有の問題ですかね。

Answer (score 2):

これは[以前に発生していた現象](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3275/)の再来です。再来した理由ですが、最近なぜか投稿エディタが以前のバージョンに戻っていることだと思われます。

#### 対処方の意見募集

ユーザー側で回避策を探すか、Stack Exchange社による修正を待つか、皆さんの意見をお聞きしたいです。

##### 回避策を探す

回避策を探す場合、この箇所がなぜかMarkdownとして解釈されていることを考慮してバックスラッシュによりエスケープを試みる、などの試行錯誤を行います。

##### 修正を待つ

Stack Exchange社による修正を待つ場合、このまま待つだけです。とても長く待つことになるかも知れません。